# jQuery sortable - disable single item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a few lists with draggable elements.  When the user moves any element to a new place $.ajax is called so the server can record the element's change in position.  While I can disable sorting for the whole list, I really only want to disable sorting for the moved element until $.ajax receives a success message.

```
update: function(event, ui) {
  ui.item.sortable('disable');
  $.ajax({options}, success: function() {
    ui.item.sortable('enable');
  });
}
```

I've done a lot of research so far, and can only get the whole list to disable.  Any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong, or is this not possible?

Comment: Sorting a list affects all items in that list, so it makes sense to disable the entire list until your changes have been recorded. Your other option might be to store the state on the client side and record changes once (e.g. via button click).

Comment: To elaborate on @randy's comment, your design amounts to associating an AJAX request with each individual element instead of the whole list. Even if it was possible (and it probably is), you cannot guarantee your AJAX requests will actually reach the server in the same order they were sent. The request for your second drag operation might be received and processed before the request for your first drag operation, which would probably not be what you want.

Comment: Yes, I understand this point, and will probably go with that in the end now that I think about it.  Currently, using the answer I found below, it works pretty good until you turbo drag your way to a crash.

Comment: After searching for ways to queue ajax requests, I stumbled on to some plugins.  This ajaxQueue plugin https://gist.github.com/1039247 looks like it will do the trick.  So, as sortables get moved around they are disabled until their ajax request succeeds, all in the order they were moved.  :D

Answer (score 3):

Sortable's cancel setting allows you to cancel sortable calls using selectors. I added the following line --

`cancel:'.updating'`

...and then I add and remove the class around the $.ajax call.

I don't know how I had missed this all day yesterday.  :D/